# Expo Android stand alone Google sign in error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

When I try to sign in with google inside an android stand alone app, it gives the following error:
{"framesToPop":1,"code":"GOOGLE_ERROR"}

This is the app.json(changed the last four digits of hash and apikey, just for stack-overflow  )

`{
  "expo": {
    "name": "flux-scrollable",
    "description": "An empty new project",
    "slug": "flux-scrollable",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "19.0.0",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.anonsment.chat",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "apiKey": "AIzaSyD5d-Y6MKS3wmxUOHvBTGhIMPOmZC9mvdc",
          "certificateHash": "F6B135645BC1D38C2FF5CE2C7BC3E7C573CCA943"
        }
      }
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "primaryColor": "#cccccc",
    "icon": "./assets/icons/app-icon.png",
    "loading": {
      "icon": "./assets/icons/loading-icon.png",
      "hideExponentText": false
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": [
        "ttf",
        "mp4"
      ]
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}`

Code for login

`const { type, user } = await Google.logInAsync({ 
    androidStandaloneAppClientId:'173851312683-pittv77ag7tn3tpq26bvu6d5nirbs5dr.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
    iosStandaloneAppClientId: '<IOS_CLIENT_ID>', 
    androidClientId: '603386649315-9rbv8vmv2vvftetfbvlrbufcps1fajqf.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
    iosClientId: '603386649315-vp4revvrcgrcjme51ebuhbkbspl048l9.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
    scopes: ['profile', 'email'] 
});`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to add `behavior: 'web'` in your code

```
const { type, user } = await Google.logInAsync({ 
    androidStandaloneAppClientId:'173851312683-pittv77ag7tn3tpq26bvu6d5nirbs5dr.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
    iosStandaloneAppClientId: '<IOS_CLIENT_ID>', 
    androidClientId: '603386649315-9rbv8vmv2vvftetfbvlrbufcps1fajqf.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
    iosClientId: '603386649315-vp4revvrcgrcjme51ebuhbkbspl048l9.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
    behavior: 'web',
    scopes: ['profile', 'email'] });
```

Comment: It actually worked when I clicked on web in oauth client id in Google credentials